# difference between using std::move and adding 0 to the number?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I'm curious about that is there any practical difference between using `std::move` to convert an l-value integer to r-value, and adding a `0` to that integer? or any other neutral arithmetic operation (multiplying by `1`, subtracting `0`, etc).

Adding `0`:

```cpp
int f(int&& i){
    i++;
    return i;
}


int main(){
    int x = 43;
    f(x+0);
}
```

Using `std::move`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int f(int&& i){
    i++;
    return i;
}


int main(){
    int x = 43;
    f(std::move(x));
}
```

I know we cannot perform such neutral actions on all types, but my question is specially about integral numbers not other types.

Comment: `std::move` is intentional and clear, whereas `x+0` could be optimized (or not optimized, resulting in an unnecessary `addi`), and hides what you are attempting to do.

Comment: less confused readers is a practical difference

Comment: note that for an `int` a move is a copy anyhow, so I'd suggest to fix `f(int)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So there is no reason using refrences for `int`?

Comment: Semantically the difference is huge. std::move shows intent, +0 requires that you are absolutely sure the compiler will have the desired side effect.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, pretty sure the `std::move` is more expressive that weird `i+0`, but I'm curious about it's internal implementations.

Comment: _"So there is no reason using refrences for `int`?"_ - Yes, if you want to make changes to the variable passed in to the function

Comment: There is no reason to move an `int` rather than copying it. In the presence of another overload `int&&` argument can make sense.

Comment: move and rvalue references for interger types have no benefit. References to ints have meaning if you want to use an int as an in/out parameters of your functions (not my prefered design pattern though).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, or in template functions

Comment: Moving reference on `int` is weird and unnecessary. Doesn't some static analysis tool doesn't complain about such thing?

Comment: @MarekR I've written it in vim :)

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi how that's relevant?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think maybe some advanced IDEs have static analysis tools and hint about such problems. But this is written in vim (knowing that probably many plugins for this purpose are available)

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi editor and static analysis tools are orthogonal. THough they can be  integrated into same environment,  static analysis tools is primarily a function or module of build toolset or compiler. especially if you don't use IDE, you should look into how to activate or invoke one, saves time on actual compiling. E.g.  Microsoft's Intellisense isn't actually static analysis tool, it's an ad hoc code analist while their compiler also got some static analysis functions, manifesting as warnings. The compiler may be implemented differently from what IDE "plugin" would assume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::move(x)` and `x+0` do not do the same thing.

The former gives you an rvalue (specifically xvalue) referring to `x`. The latter gives you a rvalue (specifically prvalue) which (after temporary materialization) refers to a temporary object with lifetime ending after the full-expression.

So `f(x+0);` does not cause `x` to be modified, while `f(std::move(x))` does.

Taking a rvalue-reference to an `int` specifically is probably pointless. Moving and copying scalar types is exactly the same operation, so there is no benefit over just `int&`.

And your function both returns the result by-value and tries to modify the argument. Typically, it should do only one of those things. If it takes a reference and modifies the argument it should either have `void` return value or return a reference to the argument. If it ought to return the result by-value, then it doesn't need to be passed a reference and can just take a `int` parameter. (It would be ok to both modify the argument and return by-value if the value returned was unrelated to the new value of the argument, e.g. as in `std::exchange` returning the old value of the argument.)

Comment: that last paragraph is IMHO nonsense. as an example take std::exchange that basically does precisely that.

Comment: @engf-010 `std::exchange` returns the previous value. If it returned the new value, I would expect it to return a reference to the argument instead.

Comment: Previous or current value ,there can be all kinds of reasons why one would return either. Why do you expect a reference as return? (sometimes I do and sometime I don't) ,it all depends. Don't assume to much (I try not to).

Comment: Or `operator ++()`/ `operator ++(int)`.

Comment: I would argue though that in `f(std::move(x))` it doesn't matter that `x` is modified because after a move it's in an unspecified state. The functions signature does not guarantee accessing `x` after the call has any meaningful result. Don't write interfaces where the semantic is not clear from the type unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a difference? Yes. This is easily demonstrating by adding one line to your examples.

**First case:**

```cpp
int f(int&& i){
    i++;
    return i;
}


int main(){
    int x = 43;
    f(x+0);
    return x; // New line that uses `x`
}
```

Exit code 43 because the value of `x` was not changed.

**Second case**

```cpp
#include <utility> // More precise header

int f(int&& i){
    i++;
    return i;
}


int main(){
    int x = 43;
    f(std::move(x));
    return x; // New line that uses `x`
}
```

Exit code 44 because the value of `x` was changed (inside `f()`).

Admittedly, the second case looks questionable because it uses the value of `x` after applying `std::move` to `x`. Then again, that is another reason there is a difference. The expression `std::move(x)` implies that there is no further use for (the value of) `x` after that expression, whereas there is no such implication from the expression `x+0`.

---

> but my question is specially about integral numbers not other types.

It seems kind of pointless to be concerned specifically with moving integers (or other primitive types). For simple types, moving is the same as copying. If it were not for class types, there would have been no reason to introduce rvalue references and move semantics to the language.